# How can I edit the contents of the printable invoice for Ubercart order?

Tags: 7, theming, commerce, ubercart

I need to add some text and a few extra order fields (and user profile fields, if possible) to the printable invoice that is accessed via a link like this: http://mysite.com/admin/store/orders/12345/invoice/print

I used grepWin to find all instances of the phrase "Purchasing Information:" (which is on the invoice), and that phrase was found in two files: uc-packing-slip.tpl.php and uc-order--customer.tpl.php. Unfortunately, changes to those files have no effect on the printable invoice (I tried placing the modified tpl files in my theme's templates/ folder as well as in their original location.

The only way I could get a "reaction" was to change the contents of the file uc_order-invoice-page.tpl.php. However, its contents are merely as follows:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a printable Ubercart invoice.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_uc_order_invoice_page()
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language ?>" lang="<?php print $language->language ?>" dir="<?php print $language->dir ?>">

<head>
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .buttons {
      text-align: right;
      margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    }
  </style>
  <style type="text/css" media="print">
    .buttons {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="<?php print t('Print invoice'); ?>" onclick="window.print();" />
  </div>

  <?php print $content; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried adding some of the order fields to that file, replacing `<?php print $content; ?>`, but it did not work. I suppose if I can find out the source of the "content" that is being "printed", I would be in good shape. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Ubercart Register Invoice](https://drupal.org/project/uc_register_invoice), this will allow you to define new email templates for invoice emails ... these same templates should also be visible/useable by your sites Theme.

> Registers invoice templates with Ubercart so they appear on and can be
>   selected for the Ubercart "E-mail an order invoice" Rules action.
>
> Registers invoice templates with Drupal so they can be used to theme
>   the invoice data.
>
> Provides extensive instructions and feedback on how to configure
>   invoice templates.

See the README. You name your template: `uc-order--*.tpl.php` and it will be seen by the system. Also see the built-in help (prior and after creating a template) at http://mysite.com/admin/help#uc_register_invoice

Comment: Tenken, this may be better asked in a new question, but can you tell me how I would print the contents of a User CCK field on the template? The field is "field_data_field_allergies" in the database, and I'd like to print its content on that invoice template. Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like you need to create some custom module function(s) to add the field as a `$variable[]` entry visible to your custom template. There is documentation here http://www.ubercart.org/docs/developer/17385/changing_invoice_templates_ubercart_23_and_later

Comment: I feel like I am almost there. I found this snippet elsewhere & modified it. It prints the allergy info, but it is the allergy info for the currently-logged-in user (me):   <?php
                    global $user;
                    $user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
                    
                    $allergies = $user_fields->field_allergies['und']['0']['value'];
                    
                    print $allergies;
                    ?>   

Anything in that code that I could change so that it will pull in the allergy info for the user associated with the order being viewed?

Comment: This code worked (courtesy of longwave on the Drupal.org forums):   <?php
  $user_fields = user_load($order->uid);
  $allergies = $user_fields->field_allergies['und']['0']['value'];
  print $allergies;
?>